Preconfigure WiFi settings in Ubuntu Core 24 image with Raspberry Pi
I'm building a custom Ubuntu Core 24 image for a Raspberry Pi 3 and want to set a list of WiFi networks for it to auto-connect to. I found this post and modified the 24 branch of the pi-gadget snap to use a specific WiFi network:
# ...
defaults:
    system:
        pi-config:
            display-rotate: 3
        system:
            network:
                netplan:
                    network:
                        wifis:
                            wlan0:
                                access-points:
                                    WIFI_NAME:
                                        auth:
                                            key-management: "psk"
                                            password: "WIFI_PASSWORD"
    01sV9tv4UTUQTU3jYsAF1gJ5qv7ZqGls:  # wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk
        url: https://example.com/

However, the only thing actually being applied from this is setting the wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk default URL. The pi doesn't connect to WiFi and the display is not rotated.
The model I'm using does not show console-conf (I think Ubuntu frame is overriding it).
But even when I remove console-conf or make it optional, the WiFi settings still seem to be ignored. Are there any additional settings that need to be set in the gadget for WiFi to work?

You used the correct version 1 schema for Netplan, used by Ubuntu Core 20 and 22.
Ubuntu Core 24 appears to have moved to a new version 2 schema for Netplan, with the following format:
        system:
            network:
                netplan:
                    network:
                        version: 2
                        wifis:
                            wlp0s1:
                                access-points:
                                    "WIFI_NAME":
                                        password: "WIFI_PASSWORD"

(Nowhere does the official Ubuntu Core documentation or Netplan documentation state anything about "version 1 schema" or "version 2 schema". I just noticed the "version: 2" part and made assumptions and inferences about the rest.)
